# VBA - Runtime error 457 when adding japanese key into dict

Tags: vba, dictionary

I create a Japanese Dictionary but It not work properly.
when i add element keys (japanese character) into dict, run-time errors 457 appear

> This key is already associated with an element of this collection ".

in debug, i find duplicated key is:  "•S" and "•s".
Reality, it's different.   ("•S" = 百 ; "•s"= 不)

[image]

any way to pass?

Comment: If you are using a Scripting.Dictionary you may need to set the <dict>.CompareMode to vbBinaryCompare

Comment: @freeflow dictionaries can recognize caps by default... it should be something more of the symbols... maybe VBA can't tell the difference